# Custom Logging mechanism: Master Operation with n-Operation Details or Child operations

Tags: c#-4.0, logging, workflow-foundation-4, entity-framework-4.3

I'm trying to implement logging mechanism in a Service-Workflow-hybrid application. The requirements for logging is that instead for independent log action, each log must be considered as a detail operation and placed against a parent/master operation. So, it's a parent-child and goes to database table(s). This is the primary reason, NLog failed.

To help understand better, I'm diving in a generic detail. This is how the application flow goes:

[image: Process Flow]

Now, the Main entry point of the application (normally called Program.cs) is **Platform**. It initializes an engine that is capable of listening incoming calls from ISDN lines, VoIP, or web services. The interface is generic, so any call that reaches the **Platform** triggers *OnConnecting()*. *OnConnecting()* is a thread-safe event and can be triggered as many times as system requires.

Within *OnConnecting()*, a new instance of our custom Workflow manager is launched and the context is a custom object called **ProcessingInfo**:

```
new WorkflowManager<ZeProcessingInfo>();
```

Where, ZeProcessingInfo:

```
var ZeProcessingInfo = new ProcessingInfo(this, new LogMaster());
```

As you can see, the **ProcessingInfo** is composed of **Platform** itself and a new instance of **LogMaster**. **LogMaster** is defined in an independent assembly.

Now this **LogMaster** is available throughout the **WorkflowManager**, all the Workflows it launches, all the activities within any running *Workflow*, and passed on to external code called from within any *Activity*. Now, when a new **LogMaster** is initialized, a *Master Operation* entry is created in the database and this **LogMaster** object now lives until this call is ended after a series of very serious roller coaster rides through different workflows. Upon every call of *OnConnecting()*, a new Master Operation is created and maintained.

The **LogMaster** allows for calling a *AddDetail()* method that adds new child detail under the internally stored Master Operation (distinguished through a Guid Primary Key). The **LogMaster** is built upon Entity Framework.

And, I'm able to log under the same Master Operation as many times as I require. But the application requirements are changing and there is a need to log from other assemblies now. There is a **Platform Server** assembly witch is a Windows Service that acts as a server listening to web service based calls and once a client calls a method, *OnConnecting* in **Platform** is triggered.

I need a mechanism to somehow retrieve the related LogMaster object so that I can add detail to the same Master Operation. But **Platform Server** is the once triggering the *OnConnecting()* on the **Platform** and thus, instantiating **LogMaster**. This creates a redundancy loop.

Also, failure scenarios are being considered as well. If LogMaster fails, need to revert to Event Logging from Database Logging. If Event Logging is failed (or not allowed through unified configuration), need to revert to file-based (XML) logging.

I hope I have given a rough idea. I don't expect code but I need some strategy for a very seamless plug-able configurable logging mechanism that supports Master-Child operations.

Thanks for reading. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I've read this question a number of times and it was pretty hard to figure out what was going on. I don't think your diagram helps at all. If your question is about trying to retrieve the master log record when writing child log records then I would forget about trying to create normalised data in the log tables. You will just slow down the transactional system in trying to do so. You want the log/audit records to write as fast as possible and you can later aggregate them when you want to read them.

Create a de-normalised table for the logs entries and use a single Guid in that table to track the session/parent log master. Yes this will be a big table but it will write fast.

As for guaranteed delivery of log messages to a destination, I would try not to create multiple destinations as combining them later will be a nightmare but rather use something like MSMQ to emit the audit logs as fast as possible and have another service pick them up and process them in a guaranteed delivery manner. ETW (Event Logging) is not guaranteed under load and you will not know that it has failed.

Comment: I think you did understood as your answers are already targeting my later concerns like best mechanism and performance.

Comment: Also, The logging throughout the Workflows is OK. I need to take care of logging in the rest of solution with around 20 console apps, 15 websites, 14 WCFs, etc...

Comment: I was using log4net. Needed Master-Detail type logging so moved away towards a custom solution. log4net and nlog need too much app.config configuration and i need to manage configurations manually.